# Get username in url [Django] [mongoengine]

Tags: python, django, mongodb, authentication, mongoengine

I am using django 1.7 with mongoengine. I have created a **class Projects** :

```
class Projects(Document):
    user = ReferenceField(User, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)
    p_name = StringField(max_length=70, required=True)
    author = StringField(max_length=70, required=True)
    url = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    short_discription = StringField(max_length=100, required=True)
    long_discription = StringField()
    logo_url = StringField(max_length=200, required=False)
    logo = ImageField(size=(250, 250, True))
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.p_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.p_name = self.p_name
        return super(Projects, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_project', args=[self.p_name])

    def get_edit_url(self):
        return reverse('update', args=[self.id])

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('delete', args=[self.id])
```

and i am referencing and storing user in my mongodb through **my views** :

```
class new_project(CreateView):
    model = Projects
    form_class = NewProjectForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('registered')
    def get_template_names(self):
        return["new_project.html"]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super(new_project, self).form_valid(form)
```

and **mongodb JSON** format looks like this :

```
"user" : ObjectId("54db3e5d7818f4253e5da0db"),
```

I want to to create user profile where they can see their all projects, for that i created a **view** :

```
class UserProjectsListView(ListView):
    model = Projects
    context_object_name = "project"

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ["view_user.html"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

and my **urls.py** :

```
url(r'^new_project/', new_project.as_view(),name='new_project'),
url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[\w\d]+)', view_project.as_view(), name='view_project'),
url(r'^user/(?P<pk>[\w\d]+)/$', UserProjectsListView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

**The problem with this is that i have to use the object id only in my url, but want to use username instead. Because on the template it renders only username not the object id**.

Does anyone know how to **use username in urls instead of object id**, because rendering object id on template would not be good for security purpose also.

my user creation form :

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.Form):
    error_messages = {
    'duplicate_username': _("A user with that username already exists."),
    'duplicate_email': _("A user with that email already exists."),
    'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),


    }
    username = forms.RegexField(label=_("Username"), max_length=30,
        regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
        help_text=_("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and "
                      "@/./+/-/_ only."),
        error_messages={
            'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and "
                         "@/./+/-/_ characters.")})
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), max_length=254,
        help_text=_("Required valid email. 254 characters or fewer."),
        error_messages={
            'invalid': _("This value may contain only valid email address.")})
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text=_("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))

    def clean_username(self):
        # Since User.username is unique, this check is redundant,
        # but it sets a nicer error message than the ORM. See #13147.
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            User._default_manager.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['duplicate_username'],
            code='duplicate_username',
        )
    def clean_email(self):
        # Since User.username is unique, this check is redundant,
        # but it sets a nicer error message than the ORM. See #13147.
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        try:
            User._default_manager.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['duplicate_email'],
            code='duplicate_email',
        )

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
        return password2

    def save(self):
        user = User._default_manager.create_user(
            username=self.cleaned_data['username'],
            email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
            password=self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        return user
```

I also want to get data from three tables and i have used dev instead of class:

```
def UserProjectsListView(request,  pk):
    return render_to_response('view_user.html', {
        'tuorial' : Tutorial.objects.filter(user=pk),
        'question' : Question.objects.filter(user=pk),
        'project': Project.objects.filter(user=pk),
        })
```

**P.S. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Please reformat your code, its impossible to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MongoEngine can't simulate joins, it is very simple to do this in two separate queries:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    user = User.objects.get(username=self.kwargs['username'])
    return self.model.objects(user=user.id)
```

Comment: Hey thanks Daniel it worked perfectly, i just have one more question how i can use multiple models in it? Is there anyway for doing it. What i have used def instead of class, u can see in updated answer above.