# Saving value instead of ObjectID in ReferenceField

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, mongoengine

I am using django1.7 with mongoengine and using RefrenceField to store user in my Document, but instead of storing the name mongodb is storing objectid. Is there anyway to store name instead of objectid.

My model:

```
class Question(Document):
    user = ReferenceField(User, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)
    title = StringField(max_length=70, required=True)
    body = StringField()
    tags = StringField()
    date_modified = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    rating = IntField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.title = self.title
        return super(Question, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_question', args=[self.title])
```

A Json document sample:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55057c867818f41c7db83888"),
    "user" : ObjectId("54db3e5d7818f4253e5da0db"),
    "title" : "Question1",
    "body" : "<p>This is body for question 1</p>\r\n",
    "tags" : "tag1",
    "date_modified" : ISODate("2015-03-15T12:35:18.331Z"),
    "rating" : 0
}
```

My view code:

```
class new_category(CreateView):
    model = Category
    form_class = NewCategoryForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('registered')
    def get_template_names(self):
        return["new_category.html"]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        return super(new_category, self).form_valid(form)
```

and my url:

```
url(r'^new_question/', new_question.as_view(),name='new_question'),
```

I am using default django user model but to make changes in user model if needed will still be okay.

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: But this appears to be the correct behaviour. Why would you want anything different?

Comment: The problem occurs when i have to use the value again, only object id is shown in url, i have [asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694144/get-username-in-url-django-mongoengine) for that but didn't got any answer. @DanielRoseman

Comment: can you post view code?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is correct, I think what you're wanting to do is to automatically dereference the user object.

To do that simply change your model to reflect something like this.

```
user = ReferenceField(User, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE, dbref=True)
```

By doing this it will return a user instead of DBRef.